# mongodb collection.watch() with next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I used mongodb collection.watch() with next js 14 app router and it works well within the API and console the data each time change happen , but how do I send that data every time there is a change to the page?
and how to close  changeStream in end of the api  GET request ?

This is the code

```js
export async function GET(request, { params: { eventID } }) {
  console.log(eventID);
  try {
    const db = await getMongoDb();
    const collection = db.collection("payments");

    const pipeline = [
      {
        $match: {
          $and: [
            {
              $or: [
                { operationType: "insert" },
                {
                  operationType: "update",
                },
              ],
            },
            { "fullDocument.eventID": new ObjectId(eventID) },
          ],
        },
      },
    ];

    const changeStream = collection.watch(pipeline, {
      fullDocument: "updateLookup",
    });

    changeStream.on("change", (change) => {
      const updatedData = change.fullDocument; // New data after update
      console.log("updatedData", updatedData);
      return NextResponse.json(updatedData);
    });

    // Close the change stream when the client disconnects
  } catch (e) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: { message: e.message } },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

thank you